# How do I setup a live data feed that will update tyre prices and stock?

Tags: php, mysql, database, feed

I have been asked to create a site for a mobile tyre business. They want to have an online ordering system with a live data feed that will update the prices of tyres and quantity on a daily basis.

My problem is that I think it can be done with PHP and a MySQL database but I don't know how to populate/update the MySQL database with the data from a .CSV spreadsheet.

Can anyone help me set this up, or point me in the direction of a service that will help me set it up?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593473/how-to-upload-and-parse-a-csv-file-in-php

Comment: I created a new question as the other answers didn't seem to answer MY question. Everyone here are so ready to reduce rep without actually asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do with PHP and MySQL.

You can also refer the question which explains reading CSV and storing in MySQL [Read CSV file and store into MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816129/read-csv-file-and-store-into-mysql-database)

Also the following tutorials might be useful.

1. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/import-csv-into-mysql/
2. http://www.infotuts.com/import-csv-file-data-in-mysql-php/

Comment: I really appreciate the links to tutorials. I did try to find some but with no luck. Some one please "up" the answer, my rep is low.

Comment: Ok so my client owns a tyre business. He gets information from his supplier in .csv format (a spreadsheet with columns and rows) and I have to find a way of inserting fields like tyre width, rim size etc into a MySQL database.

Comment: I was then intending to display the details using php. However I am unsure how to make this work.

Comment: If you could post the code, we can find out whats wrong and provide a solution. If you need sample codes, you can refer to the above posted tutorials.